# why do faucet control valves use packing

Tags: plumbing

Why do faucet control knobs use a continuous rotating compression packing when other in line stops use a positive stop gate or ball valve

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Answer: because they're better in that application; for more details you'll have to look elsewhere. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about valve engineering.

Answer (score 2):

It is really simple, the packing keeps the water from leaking out of the valve stem when the valve is open.  That’s what it does and what it is for.
Ball valves also have a stem packing but it is usually an O ring. Without  the O ring, water would come out the stem when turning the valve from open to closed.

Comment: Ok, I get that there is packing.  But why is the packing used in a continuous turn eccentric bottom stem to generate compression to stop the flow.

Comment: It is cheap in the old days greased rope and or leather was used. so you have to go back to the origin of the design and the material they had available.

Comment: my question is about the positive stop.  Why use an eccentric stem when some stem packing and a solid gate will work?

Comment: You will need a time machine to figure that out but it probably has something to do with ball valves were not really possible until thermoplastic molding and higher durometer of rubber was available.

Answer (score 0):

I conject that it is because gate valves, and worn out ball valves, never close completely.  There is always a seep from such valves and in 99% of industrial applications this is acceptable. The flow from such a seep is so low and the pressure generated in a pipe of any significant diameter is so small even a small rise can keep the whole rest of the line completely dry for work.  But in a consumer application, where the flow has to stop, down to the very last drop, it is best to have an adjustable packing nut and bottoming washer, which, however cantankerous in its maintenance and durability, shuts off totally.

Comment: I think most refinery ( etc) workers would disagree that a small leak from a valve is acceptable. A little gasoline can go a long to making a problem.  So in refineries , wells , etc often two valves are used in series . Often with a bleed between them that is vented to a safe location. Of course the junk valves used in domestic service are not used in refineries, etc,

Comment: @blacksmith37 quite informative; gate valves usually?

Comment: All well-head valves ( a few up to 25,000 psi rating) are gates and most of the refinery, chem plants are gates .Pipelines will use some ball valves. Steam power valves ( about 800 F operating) are globe , a round "gate" is forced against a seat .  Many plug valves are in low pressure oil and gas production. But probably every kind of valve is used somewhere.

Comment: @blacksmith37 It seems you believe what you say. Please kindly point to a layman's reference, a handbook of some kind, and then form these comments into an answer.

Comment: More like a section of a library; maybe Wikipedia has some summary. Also manufacture info although many specialize;  Grey for well head. Cameron for well head and line pipe,  Rockwell Mfg for steam power ( if they are still in business) , Fisher for control valves. And many , many others, Also  API for well head valve specs ( 6 A) , ANSI/ASME for power and high pressure valves . Unfortunately I am obsolete now..